Proving a recursive rational sequence will eventually become integral.
This was a conjecture I found in some old scratch work of mine, if it has a source already I don't know it.
Say $x_0>2$, $x_0 = a/b$ for coprime naturals $a$ and $b$. Define for $n\ge0$, $$x_{n+1}
= x_n\lfloor x_n\rfloor.$$ Show there exists some $k\ge0$ such that $x_k$ is an integer.
My approach has been to argue by contradiction.
For $b=n$, the numerator of $x_k$ is given by $a_{0}a_{1}...a_{k}$, where $a_{k}$ is given by the recurrence $a_0 = a$ and for $k \ge 0$, $$ a_{k+1} = \lfloor (a_{0}a_{1}...a_{k})/n \rfloor. $$
The required condition becomes $a_0 a_1 ... a_{k} \ne 0 \mod n$ for all k in N.
I was able to show this for $n=2$ combining the first k conditions. Some induction on $k$ showed $a_{i} = 1 \mod 2, (0\le i < k)$ was equivalent to $a = 3 \mod 2^k$. So clearly the only solution in $a$ that satisfied this for all $k$ in $\Bbb N$ is $a=3$, violating the $x_0 > 2$ condition.
For other denominators $n$, I wasn't able to get as nice a set of conditions or see how the first $k$ conditions would collate nicely, especially when $n$ has a lot of factors. How can I prove/disprove the conjecture?

Welcome to MSE. Please check the LaTeX guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Please format properly.  here is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Improve the formatting of the question further. Then I'm sure that this interesting question will be reopened.
